# Load Properties from resources folder within JAR

Tags: java, file, properties, io, inputstream

I have a JAR file Movie Library.jar, its contents are depicted below:

[image]

The class PropertiesUtils is resides in the client.jar (shown in picture) and the properties files are in properties folder which resides in resources folder.

I am trying to load properties as:

```
String absolutePath = LazyProperties.class.getClass().getResource(filePath).getPath();
File file = new File(absolutePath);
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(stream);
```

But it is showing:

```
file:\D:\Code\MovieLibrary\build\jar\Movie%20Library.jar!\resources\properties\movie_library.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

I am unable to figure it as `System.out.println(file)` prints:

```
file:/D:/Code/MovieLibrary/build/jar/Movie%20Library.jar!/resources/properties/movie_library.properties
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the property file is inside jar file, it is no longer a physical file

```
props.load(LazyProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties/movie_libraryproperties"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Jigar `LazyProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/properties/movie_library.properties")` did the job. Can you tell me what is the syntax if the resources folder be placed in client.jar?

Comment: `LazyProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("classpath:/resources/properties/movie_library.p‌​roperties")`

Comment: @JigarJoshi : Is there any way if I want to do changes in the property file inside the jar. ?