# Issue while running executable Jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm having a lot of issue's while running a executable jar I created.

First of all I got a lot of problems when I created the jar by the usual methode in eclipse (indigo).  So I switched to the Fatjar plugin.  This solved most problems.

But not all, I still have some issue's.  For example :

[image]

The structure of my project is like this.

[image]

By the creation of the jar I all ready included the dir with the property files but he still doesn't find it?!

While running in eclipse I have no problems.

Any suggestions.  Thx all.

Comment: Show us the code that loads the properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file in jar is no more a `File`(to the filesystem), It is resource of jar, See [how to load properties file from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349044/load-properties-from-resources-folder-within-jar)

**Also See**

- [load-properties-file-in-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar)